# How to query stream table to get updates when some of my friend is tagged in a photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

my project requires get updates from my friend when they are tagged in a photo. On facebook site, such kind 'someone is tagged in a photo' message is automatically categorized in one of my frined list (for example: close friend) other than the news feed category. So I use below FQL to query the stream table:

```
SELECT post_id, source_id, updated_time, created_time, actor_id, target_id, message, attachment, comments, likes 
FROM stream 
WHERE filter_key in 
    (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter 
     WHERE uid = me() AND type = 'friendlist') 
AND is_hidden = 0 ORDER BY created_time DESC
```

But unfortunately, all updates I see on the facebook site exist in the query result except for the photo tag updates.

Does anyone know what's the issue or how can I retrieve such photo tag updates ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Similar question here: [How can I get "is now friends with" and "was tagged in" posts in Facebook Graph API?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4358026/how-can-i-get-is-now-friends-with-and-was-tagged-in-posts-in-facebook-graph-a)

Unfortunately the answer isn't what you want to hear.